# How to correctly bind callbacks to each element in a loop in Python Kivy library

Tags: python, callback, scope, kivy, closures

I have the following code:

```
from functools import partial

class DishesScreen(Screen):

    def on_pre_enter(self):
        Window.size = (800, 800)
    
        for i in range(10):
            self.layout.add_widget(AsyncImage(source='<url>', allow_stretch=True,
                                              size_hint_y=None, size_hint_x=None))
            dish_widget = self.get_params_layout()
            dish_widget.bind(on_touch_down=partial(self.move, data[i]))
            self.layout.add_widget(dish_widget)

    def get_params_layout(self):
        params_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', size_hint_y=None, spacing=10, padding=10)
        return params_layout

    def move(self, *args):
        # some actions here
        pass
```

What I want to do is to call `move()` function with parameters specific for each element in the list of `BoxLayout`'s.

If I click on the second element - I expect `move()` function execution with the parameter specific for the second element, if I click on the 7th element - I expect `move()` function execution with the parameter specific for the 7th element, etc.

Instead, no matter on which element I click, the `move()` function executes 10 times, each time it uses the parameter for the element starting from the last and ending by the first element.

I think it is because I add `dish_widget` to the `layout`: `self.layout.add_widget(dish_widget)`. And this means that when I click somewhere, actually I click on the `layout`, and the program executes all 10 `move()` functions attached to the `layout`. But cannot figure out how to change this behaviour. I need only one call of the `move()` function - the only that is attached to the element (`BoxLayout`) on which I clicked in the list. Can anybody help, please?

UPDATE:

Here is the markup:

```
<DishesScreen>:
    layout: layout
    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_x: False
        do_scroll_y: True
        GridLayout:
            id: layout
            cols:2
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: self.minimum_height
            spacing: 5, 5
```

Answer (score 1):

All of your `Widgets` will receive the `touch` event. From the [Widget Documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#module-kivy.uix.widget):

> on_touch_down(), on_touch_move(), on_touch_up() don’t do any sort of
> collisions. If you want to know if the touch is inside your widget,
> use collide_point().

So your `move()` method must do a collision test to determine if the `touch` was within the bounds of that `Widget`. Something like this:

```
def move(self, data, source, touch):
    if source.collide_point(*touch.pos):
        print('move', data)
        return True  # stop the bubbling of this touch to other widgets
```